# Equal theoremisu

Tags: arithmetic

On the label of the tiramisu pie I was eating with my roommates, it said: 3.5 equal parts.
This raised a question. 
Can you divide a pie in 3.5 equal parts?

Comment: What is meant by $3.5$ equal parts?

Comment: It really said "$3.5$ equal parts"?  That seems almost intentionally confusing.   If I had to guess, I'd say it meant "three equal parts and one of half the size of the others". We'd then have $3x+\frac x2=1$, so we'd get three parts equal to $\frac 27$ of the pie, and one part equal to $\frac 17$ of the pie.  But, really, it's just a guess.

Comment: I am inclined to say the answer is no. I interpret "equal parts" as "every part has to have the same size". Therefore the number of parts has to be integer.

Comment: "Equal theoremisu" is one of the more intriguing subject lines I've seen...

Comment: What was the context? The table of nutritional facts? As in, just a seventh of this pie will give you more sugar and salt than you should have in one day?